# Is there a way to get an extern variable (or function) by name

Tags: c, extern, std

I thought I read about a C standard library function recently that was able to return a pointer to any extern variable whose name was passed to it as a const char *.  I think that it works via linker symbols, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could be thinking of [`dlsym`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html), which is not part of the C standard library but part of the POSIX API.

Comment: Yup, this looks like it.  My mistake in thinking it was a C standard thing, POSIX is pretty close ;)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the system. `dlsym` has already been mentioned. Its Windows counterpart is [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(VS.85).aspx). In the latter case, the function needs to be not only external but exported.

Comment: +1, I was going to mention `GetProcAddress` also but he mentioned "standard library" so I ruled Windows API out.

Comment: @dreamlax: +1 for considering POSIX "more standard" than Windows API ;)